# drawing program with glut/openGL not working

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

This program is able to create a window and locate my mouse when it is on the window, however the display function does seem to work. What am I missing here?

```
float pointSize = 10.0f;
bool leftBottState;
float xvalue;
float yvalue;


void init()
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
}

void dots()
{
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glVertex3f(xvalue, yvalue, 0.0);

}


void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1, 0, 1);
    dots();
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
    

}
void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    y = 600 - y;
    if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN)
    {
        leftBottState = true;
    }
    else
    {
        leftBottState = false;
    }
}

void motion(int x, int y) 
{   
    if (leftBottState) 
    {
        std::cout << "LEFt bUTTON " << std::endl;
        xvalue = x;
        yvalue = y;
        glutPostRedisplay();
    }
}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutInitWindowSize(600, 600);
    glutCreateWindow("test");   
    glutMotionFunc(motion);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);   
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
    glutMainLoop();

    return(0);                  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a double buffered window (see [`glutInitDisplayMode`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node12.html)).

> ```cpp
> glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE);
> ```

Therefore you must call [`glutSwapBuffers`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node21.html) to swaps the buffers after rendering the scene:

```cpp
void dots()
{
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glVertex3f(xvalue, yvalue, 0.0);
    glEnd();
}
```

```cpp
void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1, 0, 1);
    dots();
 
    // glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Note, a [`glBegin` \ `glEnd`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glBegin.xml) sequence delimits the vertices of a primitive. I recommend to call this instructions in the same function, immediately before and after specifying the vertices.

[`glClear`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glClear.xml) clears the buffers and thus the entire scene. If you want to draw the points permanently, you have to remove the `glClear` instruction from the `display` function.

<s>`glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);`</s>